# JS и привязка контекста, использование скобок

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть React код:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  state={
    counter: 0,
  }
  click = ()=>{
    this.setState((prevState)=>({
      counter: ++prevState.counter
    }))
  }
  render(){
    const {counter} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>{counter}
      <button onClick={this.click}> click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Если в методе click убрать пару скобок, которая содержит`({
          counter: ++prevState.counter
        })` , то перестает работать.
Почему это происходит, помню читал статью о роли скобок, но никак не могу найти...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном примере роль скобок - разделение многозначного синтаксиса.

Как вы знаете, фигурные скобки применяются в ES6 для описания двух сущностей: структур данных и блоков кода.

В предлагаемой нотации сокращенного описания функций предполагается по стандарту, что может быть два варианта сокращенного определения функций:

1. `(ПАРАМЕТЕР[,...]) => <БЛОК КОДА>`
2. `(ПАРАМЕТЕР[,...]) => <ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ>`

При этом, первый вариант считается приоритетным, а второй преобразуется из вида

```
(params[,...]) => <ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ>
```

в вид

```
function (params[,...]){
    return <ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ>;
}
```

Так как при разборе кода блок кода имеет приоритет, то конструкция

```
(a) => {counter: ++a.counter}
```

воспринимается как код:

```
function (a){
  counter: ++a.counter
}
```

Эта функция возвращает `undefined` так как не содержит оператор return.

В этом легко убедиться при помощи онлайнового транслятора ES6 в ES5, который доступен по [ссылке](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=BQQwlABAvAfBDeBjA9gVwHYBcCmAnAXBANREgC-QA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Если же мы в коде специально уже транслятору сообщаем, что это выражение, а не блок кода (то есть ставим скобки - как признак приоритета арифметико-логической операции) то транслятор обрабатывает этот запрос как выражение и обрамляет фигурными скобками и оператором return. То есть из

```
(a) => ({counter: ++a.counter})
```

делает:

```
function (a){
  return {counter: ++a.counter}
}
```

В чем не трудно убедиться, перейдя по [ссылке](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=BQQwlABAvAfBwG8DGB7ArgOwC4FMBOAXBANTEgC-YQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Лямбда функции имеют две формы:

1. краткая: `(args) => expression` в данном случае принимаются параметры и возвращается результат вычисления `expresison`
2. полная: `(args) => {statements}` в данном случае принимаются параметры и вычисляются `statements` внутри фигурных скобок.

краткую форму можно выразить через полную:

`(args) => expression` <=> `(args) => {return expression}`

---

В данном случае возвращается литерал объекта. И если опустить круглые скобки тело функции будет рассмотрено как блок кода, а не литерал объекта.

```js
var t = 1;
var func = () => {
  counter: t++
};

console.log(func(),t);

var func2 = () => ({
  counter: t++
});

console.log(func2(), t);
```